# Is it correct to make WebApps for Ubuntu Desktop 14.04+ with "webapp-container"?

Tags: 14.04, webapps, 16.04, webapp-development

I'm trying to make a simple webapp for Ubuntu Desktop only (Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04).
To do it, I've made a *.desktop* file with the following "Exec" line:

```
Exec=webapp-container --enable-back-forward --enable-addressbar --store-session-cookies --app-id=APPLICATION_ID --webappUrlPatterns=HTTP://WEBSITE* HTTP://HOMEPAGE %u
```

The WebApp is working fine, however I noticed that the other webapps provided by ubuntu (google+, facebookmessenger, twitter...) use the "unity-webapps-runner" command

```
Exec=unity-webapps-runner -n ...
```

My question: is it ok and safe to make (and eventually share) new WebApps for Ubuntu Desktop with the **webapp-container** command, as described in [this page](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/web/ubuntu-webapps-guide/)? Or is it only for Ubuntu "Touch"?
Should I take some precautions?

Thanks in advance